# OKHTTP 3 MediaType as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" crash issue

Tags: android, crash, okhttp

I was trying to implement postman's working as following for android app:
[image]

Here is my java codes:

```
    MediaType CONTENT_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(CONTENT_TYPE)
            .addFormDataPart("phoneNumber", phone)
            .addFormDataPart("serviceType", type)
            .addFormDataPart("stripeToken", token)
            .addFormDataPart("serviceCost", String.valueOf(amount))
            .build();

    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(Const.URL_HEROKU_BASE+"payment/charge")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
```

It makes crash ...
[image]

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue when using the public api/login of this [**free rest service**](https://reqres.in/).

In **postman**, when passing body as **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** works. But in OkHttp3 MultipartBody doesn't work.

As  @shindi suggested this code works perfectly for this api.

```
RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("email", "some_email")
            .add("password", "some_password")
            .build();
```

.header() wasn't needed for the request either. Works for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Change:
MultipartBody

to:
FormBody

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not adding the content type properly:

Change this:

```
final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(Const.URL_HEROKU_BASE+"payment/charge")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
```

to:

```
final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .url(Const.URL_HEROKU_BASE+"payment/charge")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
```

and remove the `.setType(CONTENT_TYPE)` part.

Comment: If I use postman (see my question), parameters are transferred to server.. otherwise,, If I use java codes,, params are not transeferred to server..

Answer (score 1):

Let use `FormBody` as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53261129/2013887
And don't forget to use correct @RequestBody type, e.g `MultiValueMap` for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type